# Script SQL no muestra lo que deseo

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Tengo este script en SQL

```
insert into cliente (Cédula,Nombres,Apellidos)values(1312245671,"Diego Fernando","Utreras Villavicencio");
insert into cliente (Cédula,Nombres,Apellidos)values(1311549313,"Héctor Gonzalo","Utreras Villavicencio");
insert into producto (idProducto,nombreProducto)value(1,"chocolate");
insert into producto (idProducto,nombreProducto)value(2,"miel");

Insert into pedidos (idPedidos,cliente_Id,Producto_idProducto)values(1,2,1);
insert into pedidos (idPedidos,cliente_Id,Producto_idProducto)values(2,1,2);

Select pedidos.idPedidos,Id,Nombres
from cliente inner join pedidos on cliente.Id = pedidos.cliente_Id
```

Me gustaría mostrar el id del pedido, el id del cliente que lo pidío y el nombre pero en este caso el nombre del cliente no me muestra bien.
Me muestra el nombre del cliente 2 veces. ¿Qué tendría que corregir en mi Script para que me pueda mostrar correctamente? Tal como está ahorita el problema es que me muestra Diego Fernando aunque el otro pedido lo hizo otro cliente.
O sea como hago para que me muestre que el primer pedido o sea el de idPedidos 1 lo hizo Hector Gonzalo y el de idPedidos 2 lo hizo Diego Fernando

Asi son las tablas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en las imágenes el Script me muestra el listado de los pedidos pero no me muestra bien el nombre de quién hizo los pedidos. Debería mostrar que el primer pedido lo hizo `Hector Gonzalo`

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar la definición de las tablas y el resultado que estas obteniendo?

Comment: acabo de hacer el edit @Marcos. No se si con eso ya me podrías ayudar

Comment: Así como esta planteando, el error no se puede reproducir. [Acá una demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/miCLiAkedbrSe7r13HHaVB/0). ¿Que pasa si agregas `mydb.` a las tablas en el `SELECT`?

Comment: ¿Cómo el error no se puede reproducir? Disculpa pero no entiendo @Marcos, aparte veo que en la demo que pusiste si da bien y es exactamente el mismo Script. ¿Cómo tendría que hacer entonces?

Comment: ya me di cuenta, se había introducido mal un valor en la tabla cliente. Esa era la falla @Marcos

Answer (score 0):

Con la siguiente consulta estás obteniendo todos los datos donde el `ID` del `cliente` coincida con los `cliente_Id` de la tabla `pedidos`.

```
SELECT pedidos.idPedidos,Id,Nombres
FROM cliente INNER JOIN pedidos ON cliente.Id = pedidos.cliente_Id
```

Si quieres obtener los de un cliente en específico, necesitas utilizar la condición `WHERE`. Por ejemplo, si quieres los datos del cliente con nombre "Diego Fernando":

```
SELECT pedidos.idPedidos,Id,Nombres
FROM cliente INNER JOIN pedidos ON cliente.Id = pedidos.cliente_Id 
WHERE cliente.Nombres = "Diego Fernando"
```

Esto es un ejemplo .Ten en cuenta que esto no es un campo único por lo que, si hay otro usuario con el mismo nombre, saldrá también en el listado por lo que mejor puedes buscar por la cédula que es un campo único.

PD: No utilices tildes para nombres de columnas. `Cédula` no es lo más correcto.

Comment: Entiendo el punto, gracias Adrián pero como tendría que hacer entonces para que me muestre que el pedido 1 (idPedidos) lo hizo Hector Gonzalo y el pedido 2 lo hizo Diego Fernando

Comment: Mmm, si necesitas los nombres de la persona que hizo el primer pedido con el `WHERE` ya obtienes lo que necesitas. Si haces un `SELECT cliente.Nombres` con la condición `WHERE pedidos.idPedidos = 1`  (haciendo los respectivos JOIN por supuesto) ya tendrías el nombre de quien hizo el primer pedido.

Comment: Eso si entiendo @Adrián pero quiero el nombre de la persona que hizo cada pedido, o sea el primer pedido lo hizo Hector Gonzalo y el segundo Diego Fernando. Como hago para que me muestre eso. O sea quiero una tabla de la lista de los pedidos con el nombre de quien hizo cada pedido